# Columnas dinámicas dentro de Row en React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design

Estoy trayendo noticias dinámicamente mediante una API y le di estilo a mi proyecto con la librería de Material Design [MUICss](https://www.muicss.com/).
Creo un Container, que dentro tiene su Row correspondiente, pero tengo dudas en cuanto a las columnas. Estas se generan dinámicamente, iterando sobre la cantidad de noticias que haya y crea una por cada una. En este momento estoy trabajando con *Col="md-4"*, pero el layout no queda bien ya que genera muchas columnas dentro del Row, cuando en realidad deberían ser sólo 3 por Row. El problema es que no sé cómo hacer esto, ya que se generan dinámicamente.

**El componente que contiene a cada una de las noticias:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SingleArticle from './SingleArticle';
import Row from 'muicss/lib/react/row';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class News extends Component {
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <Row>
                <TransitionGroup>
                    {this.props.news.map(singleArticle => (
                        <CSSTransition
                            key={singleArticle.url}
                            classNames="fade"
                            timeout={500}
                        >
                            <SingleArticle 
                                singleArticle={singleArticle}
                            />
                        </CSSTransition>
                    ))}
                </TransitionGroup>
            </Row>
         );
    }
}

News.propTypes = {
    news: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default News;
```

**El componente de la noticia única:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Panel from 'muicss/lib/react/panel';
import Col from 'muicss/lib/react/col';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const SingleArticle = (props) => {
    const { urlToImage, url, description, title } = props.singleArticle;

    const image = (urlToImage) ? <img src={urlToImage} alt={title} /> : '';
    return (
        <Col md="4">
            <Panel>
                {image}
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                <p>{description}</p>
                <a href={url}>+</a>
            </Panel>
        </Col>

      );
};

SingleArticle.propTypes = {
    singleArticle: PropTypes.shape({
        urlToImage: PropTypes.string,
        url: PropTypes.string,
        description: PropTypes.string,
        title: PropTypes.string
    })
}

export default SingleArticle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave para tu problema es usar la función [módulo o resto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos#.25_.28modular.29) (`%`) al momento de iterar tu lista de noticias.
Considera la siguiente solución:

```
class News extends Component {
  renderArticle(singleArticle) {
    return (
      <CSSTransition key={singleArticle.url} classNames="fade" timeout={500}>
        <SingleArticle singleArticle={singleArticle} />
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  }

  renderRow(articles) {
    return (
      <Row>
        <TransitionGroup>{articles}</TransitionGroup>
      </Row>
    );
  }

  renderRows() {
    const { news } = this.props;
    let articles = [];
    let rows = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
      const singleArticle = news[i];
      // Deberías acumular artículos para eventualmente agregarlos a la fila
      articles.push(this.renderArticle(singleArticle));
      // Se realiza % 3, ya que necesitas un comportamineto distinto cada tres
      // elementos, específicamente en la tercera iteración (i = 2, 5, 8, etc...)
      // es cuando deberías crear la fila y agregar los artículos acumulados
      if (i % 3 == 2) {
        rows.push(this.renderRow(articles));
        // Y luego vaciar el arreglo de artículos, ya que ya fueron agregados a
        // la nueva fila
        articles = [];
      }
    }
    // En caso de que haya quedado algún artículo sin agregar al arreglo de filas,
    // se agregará en esta última etapa
    if (articles.length > 0) {
      rows.push(this.renderRow(articles));
    }
    return rows;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderRows()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección. No se me había ocurrido ese razonamiento. ¡Muchas gracias!